# Sharing a User Login/Pass on SQL Server linked tables with an Access accde front end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a business case where I am developing a simple search UI, I would like to link it to our SQL Server as the performance is pretty fast when I test it. My plan is to create a few linked tables and create a tidy search form for each linked table (different datasets).

*UPDATE, here is a better description of my plan*

I have a single user ID / Password that I want to use in each ODBC connection on 4 linked SQL tables (its considered an APP ID at my company, the PW never changes). There will be 4 forms that link to each of the tables and each user will have their own accde db with a launch file that places a copy on the users profile drive and opens it from there. This allows each user to have their own copy of the accde file and everyone to have only one "launch" file.

This search UI, will have upwards of 2000 users, who knows how many actually executing a search at any given time. Security is not a concern as it is a DB on an internal SQL Server which is managed by our IT area. The end users are all internal employees.

**Will using just the one ID potentially lock out my APP ID and cause major issues?**

**Will MS Acess no longer be a major choke point if each user has their own accde file?**

Thank you and sorry that my first version of this question was not 100% clear, thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, this question is off-topic, as it's broad and opinion-soliciting (and not actually a programming question). That said: I think that, given the tremendous number of security breaches in the news lately, you should easily be able to make an informed decision to the risk of doing such a thing. Even embedding username+password in an app has its own risks, since people can reverse-engineer apps (which is why app-tier database access is so popular). Again, not gonna tell you how to design your security. But this is Common Sense 101.

Comment: Each Application  should have it's own Application ID.  If these two forms are for the same application use one ID. I'm also assuming each has connection pooling enabled so that really you likely will never have more than 20 connections as each pool'ed connection is "reused" (assuming max connection for each site/app is 10.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am asking if there is a technical limitation to sharing the app id. I should state this is an app Id for a db on an internal SQL server that is managed security wise by our it Dept. Only internal employees will be using it. This is new Territory for me, so I am trying to make sure it doesn't break. . I will see if connection pooling is enabled on the db. The linked tables will all be using oledb connections to the db using the app Id.

Comment: And the search form will likely just be ms access accde file.

Comment: I lied, odbc connection

Comment: Updated the original question because my initial post was horrible. I hope the new one is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured I would circle back and post up what I did. While providing a singular app ID with a File DSN in a shared location for the Access Front end *would have worked*, it was ultimately not the most stable solution.

Since I am in a large corporate environment, my options were extremely limited. That said, I was able to have a read only role added to the database I manage, sourced an "Active Directory Group" that had the membership I needed (as a bonus, the membership was managed at the corporate level!) and I added the AD Group to the read only role.

I then created a File DSN using windows authentication security, placed it in a shared folder location (where I also added the same AD Group to a read only role on the folder) and emailed out a shortcut to a simple batch file launcher that copies an ACCDE database to the users profile drive.

The accde houses all the necessary search forms, logic and linked tables needed for the end user. I even build in a back door that crashes out the end users (with a warning) with a simple file rename. The front end runs surprisingly fast with the test group of 100 individuals and is rolling out to 500 next week.

Viola. Hope this helps someone trying to do something similar.